# Re-run a line of code during matlab debugging like Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab

Is there a possibility to re-run already executed line in matlab like Visual Studio. In Visual Studio, one can set the next line for execution in debug mode. Does matlab have this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not perfectly sure whether this is what you are looking for, but you can highlight some code with your mouse and then press F9 (note that this is the Windows shortcut, not sure whether linux or OSX are the same). The highlighted code will then be executed, this feature is called "evaluate selection".

I am not aware that you can interfere with the order of code execution in MATLAB in another way (except typing stuff in the command line while debugging).

**Warning:**

As suggested by Dan in the comment, note must be taken that this will alter the workspace and naturally this can interfere with the execution of your program in undesireable and at first unintuitive ways. You should keep this in the back of your head at all times while altering the workspace during program execution.

Comment: Just be aware that doing this will alter the state of your workspace, you will not be in the identical state that you were prior to running the command. This is often desirable for debugging though as it allows you to test fixes while debugging.

Comment: @Dan Good comment, i'll add a warning.

Comment: You can create those sections in MATLAB by introducing double `%` sign (as `%%`) in the code.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Note that cell content execution does not work inside functions, only in scripts.

Comment: @sovbek: Your solution something similar to copy line of code in command  window and execute it. However, I want to change the execution flow and somehow, instead of restarting the whole script, I want to redo all calculation after a specific line. However, it is nice trick, instead of copy line, just select and press F9 button.

Comment: @User1551892 You can also select multiple lines of code at once. As i mentioned in my answer though, i am not aware that you can alter the execution order in Matlab in a way such that it would "goto" a certain line.